# Toolbar vs appcompat v7-21 toolbar

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

What is the difference between the two? what all features are included in toolbar thats not in v7-21 toolbar? What all limitations are there in using v7-21 tollbar in place of toolbar?

Comment: I think it's a backward compatibility thing.

Comment: yeah, it is, but the thing is that i want to know how features will be different if we use v7 toolbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) and the [AppCompat Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) you can see that functionally, there aren't any differences between the two. Of course the SDK level required differs between the two and to use the `Toolbar` you have to call `setActionBar(mToolbar);` but with the support `Toolbar` you have to call `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);`

Comment: Other than that, Appcompat Toolbar supports all the functions that Toolbar supports.. is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant when I said they're functionally identical